# Like description does not display on Timeline

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-apps

I made an app for Facebook. The 'like' description shows up in share but on people's Timeline it does not appear. I have debugged and tried over and over but it's still not working. The image appears, the link, the site name but no description.

These are the metatags I use:

```
<meta property="og:{tagName}" content="{tagValue}"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:title" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:url" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:type" content="blog"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="giggle">
```

I just don't understand why the description appears on the main Facebook page but not the Timeline.

Answer (score 0):

After having done an extensive amount of digging for a project of mine that had the same problem (that's how I found this question).  I've come to the conclusion that this is the basic facebook functionality, and there's no way around it.

I checked out two popular websites that should be doing it correctly and here you can see the New York Times in News Feed:

[image]

and Time Line:

[image]

Also, Upworthy in News Feed:

[image]

and Time Line:

[image]